# How to add includeExceptionDetailInFaults to app.config generated by scvutil

Tags: wcf

I have the following app.config generated by scvutil. I'm new to WCF and I've been trying to debug and error and wish to add includeExceptionDetailInFaults=true to this file but not getting anywhere. Can someone tell me what to add exactly, I've tried adding servicebehaviors but keep getting an error.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
                messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
                useDefaultWebProxy="true">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                    maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                <security mode="None">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
                        realm="" />
                    <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
                </security>
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:8084/Service1.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" contract="IService1"
            name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`includeExceptionDetailInFaults` is a **server** property <sup>1</sup>, which doesn't really apply on the client. If you want to set that property, you'll need to change the server side, not the client side (or whatever is generated by `svcutil`.

---

<sup>1</sup> That property can be set on the client as well, but only for *duplex* contracts, where the client is acting as a service. Since you're using `basicHttpBinding`, this is not the case for you.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, I set on the server and it works